# sort on a vector doesn't work

Tags: c++, vector, scope, iterator

Why doesn't the sort function work in the example below? I have no warning nor a compiler error. Is this normal? How can I fix it?
Thank you in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>


int main (){

    typedef std::vector<double> VecDoub;    
    VecDoub a;
    a.push_back(2.01);
    a.push_back(1.01);
    a.push_back(0.01);
    a.push_back(4.01);

    VecDoub::iterator it = a.begin();

    while (it != a.end()){
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
        ++it;
    }

    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());

    while (it != a.end()){
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you see when debugging it? I see it did sort it.

Comment: Explain this code to your rubber duck.

Comment: You didn't reset `it` to `begin` before your second printing loop

Comment: Did you avoid `for` loop specially to produce this error?

Comment: Didn't pay attention to that. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to reset `it` to `a.begin()` before the second `while`.

Answer (score 2):

After the first loop the iterator `it` is equal to `a.end().` As result the second while loop is not executed.

It is a general mistake when the scope of a local variable is too large.:)
Instead of the while loops you could use for loops with the variable it that has scope of the each loop.

```
for ( VecDoub::iterator it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it; ){
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

Or it would be even better to use the range-based for loop. For example

```
for ( auto x : a ) std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sort function "sorted" your container correctly, however your control did not enter your second while loop to display the result, since its breaking condition was valid: `it == a.end`. So you *Thought* it did not sort where in fact you just did not see it.

This should work:

```
it = a.begin(); // reset or declare new
while (it != a.end()) {
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    ++it;
}
```